# Satellite image of agriculture land cover for some country

Tags: data, remote-sensing, agriculture

I am looking for a free satellite image of agriculture land cover for North Korea. Can someone guide me to any free resource.

Is it available on earth Explorer, if yes, which image should I download.

Comment: If this is likely to be open data then I think you should research/ask this at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Posted same question on Open data forum as suggested

Comment: Cross-posted as https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/satellite-image-of-agriculture-land-cover-for-north-korea

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for agricultural cultivated area [GLC30](http://www.globallandcover.com/GLC30Download/index.aspx) could provide enough information for you.

If you want to perform your own classification I would recommend you to use Landsat 8 data. You can download it for free from [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). You can choose an area and a date you are interested in.